# Matlab - filter matrix by having specific values

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a matrix `A` and a vector `b`. I don't know their sizes, the size varies because it is the output of another function. What I want to do is filter `A` by a column (let's say *j*th column) which has at least one value that is in `b`.

How do I do this without measuring the size of b and concatenating every filtered result. Right now, the code is like this (assume *j* is a given value)

```
bsize=size(b,1);
for i=1:bsize
    if i==1
        a=A(A(:,j)==b(i),:);
    else
        a=[a; A(A(:,j)==b(i),:)];
    end
end
```

I want to code a faster solution.

I am adding a numerical example just to make it clear. Let's say

```
A=[2  4
   7 14
  11 13
  15 14]
```

and `b=[4 14]`

What I'm trying to do is filter to obtain the `A` matrix whose values are 4 and 14 in the second column, the elements of `b` to obtain the following output.

```
A=[2  4
   7 14
  15 14]
```

In my data `A` has more than 12000 rows and `b` has more than 100 elements. It doesn't always have to be the second column, sometimes the column index changes but that's not the problem now.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding what your objective is.  Can you show us a numerical example and expected output?

Comment: @rayreng Thank you. I added a small example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function to create a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) based on column `j=2` of `A` and vector `b`, and use that index into the rows of `A`:

```
output = A(ismember(A(:,j), b), :);
```